# Matplotlib Pyplot ImageGrid Figure Problem

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm stuck at a problem with AXES_GRID1 (https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html). Specifically in the use of ImageGrid().

The following code prepares and shows a figure exactly like intended:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                nrows_ncols=(3, 4), 
                axes_pad=0.5,
                cbar_mode='single',
                cbar_location='right',
                cbar_pad=0.5,
                direction='row',
                )
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Overview of the figure to be created]

But as soon as I add my figures to the relevant axes like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                nrows_ncols=(3, 4), 
                axes_pad=0.5,
                cbar_mode='single',
                cbar_location='right',
                cbar_pad=0.5,
                direction='row',
                )
rc = 0
for season in ('MAM', 'JJA', 'SON'):
    im = dat_fluo_ref.sel(time=select_season(dat_fluo_ref['time.season'], season)).groupby('time.hour').mean('time').radiance.plot.pcolormesh(
        ax=grid[rc + 0], vmin=0, vmax=0.5, cmap='Spectral_r', add_colorbar=False,)

    im = dat_fluo_inc.sel(time=select_season(dat_fluo_inc['time.season'], season)).groupby('time.hour').mean('time').radiance.plot.pcolormesh(
        ax=grid[rc + 1], vmin=0, vmax=0.5, cmap='Spectral_r', add_colorbar=False,)

    im = dat_full_ref.sel(time=select_season(dat_full_ref['time.season'], season)).groupby('time.hour').mean('time').radiance.plot.pcolormesh(
        ax=grid[rc + 2], vmin=0, vmax=0.5, cmap='Spectral_r', add_colorbar=False,)

    im = dat_full_inc.sel(time=select_season(dat_full_inc['time.season'], season)).groupby('time.hour').mean('time').radiance.plot.pcolormesh(
        ax=grid[rc + 3], vmin=0, vmax=0.5, cmap='Spectral_r', add_colorbar=False)
    rc += 4
cbar = grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Then the resulting figure (see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq6CL.png)) is no longer looking like the preview (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO8a7.png)).

It is probably an issue with the parameters passed to ImageGrid. 
[image: Figure created but totally wrong aspect ratio. Looks compressed.]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageGrid` is attempting to maintain a square shape for pixels. If you have many more columns than lines, that may not be what you are trying to accomplish. Try passing `aspect=False` when constructing the ImageGrid.

Compare:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig = plt.figure()
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                 nrows_ncols=(3, 4),
                 axes_pad=0.5,
                 cbar_mode='single',
                 cbar_location='right',
                 cbar_pad=0.5,
                 direction='row',
                 aspect=False
                )
for ax in grid.axes_all:
    ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random(size=(5,20)))
```

[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig = plt.figure()
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                 nrows_ncols=(3, 4),
                 axes_pad=0.5,
                 cbar_mode='single',
                 cbar_location='right',
                 cbar_pad=0.5,
                 direction='row',
                 aspect=True
                )
for ax in grid.axes_all:
    ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random(size=(5,20)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Diziet Asahi that did the trick. Although they write in https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html that the default is "False" this is consequently only true for AxisGrid, wheras ImageGrid has "True" as default. 
Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If that solution resolved your problem, consider accepting the answer using the checkmark on the left to close the topic. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)